# is every finite rank 2 group a quotient of a rank 2 center free group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group generated by 2 elements. Must there exist a finite center-free group $G'$ generated by at most 2 elements and a surjection $G'\rightarrow G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Here is one way of constructing such a group $G'$. Let $S$ be a finite nonabelian simple group with order divisible by some prime $p$ that does not divide $|G|$. Then let $G'$ be the standard wreath product $S \wr G$ of $S$ by $G$. Then certainly $Z(G')=1$, so we just need to show that $G'$ is $2$-generated.

Let $B$ be the base group of $G'$. Then $B$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G'$. Let $G = \langle a,b \rangle$. Now $G$ centralizes the diagonal subgroup of $B$, which is isomorphic to $S$. Let $c$ be an element of this subgroup of order $p$ and consider the subgroup $H=\langle ac, b \rangle$ of $G'$. Then $H$ projects onto $G$, and some power of $ac$ has order $p$ and lies in $B$, so $H \cap B \ne 1$. Hence $H=G'$.

I suspect you can can find a$2$-generated $G'$ with $Z(G)=1$ and normal elementary abelian subgroup $N$ with $G'/N \cong G$, but I can't quite see how to prove that.

Comment: nice! I had completely forgotten about the wreath product!